# Excluding label names in simple Neo4j Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Usually I can find everything I need already on SO but not this time. I'm looking for a very simple way to exclude labels, for example `(pseudo code)`:

```
match (n) where n not in (Label1, Label2) return n
```

Sorry about crappy query. In short I have labels x,y,z and I want to return all of them apart from z.

Thnx!

Comment: match (n:X, (r:Y)  return n, r <-- I don't want to do this as I have too many labels to include

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This should do it:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT n:Label1 AND NOT n:Label2
RETURN n;
```

Comment: Great @EdBaker, please mark my answer as correct to help others.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long list of labels you want to exclude, I find this syntax to be helpful:

```
match (n)
where not labels(n) in [['label1'],['label2'],['label3']]
```