# neo4j how to return all paths from a selected starting node

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Hello I have a graph db like this one:
[image]

my wish is to retrieve all the nodes connected through the `r` relationship starting from a selected node. E.g.

if I select `a`, then I expect two rows as a response:

```
a,b,c
a,d
```

if I select `b` then I expect one row:

```
b,c
```

I tried with `match p=(:a)-[:r*..]->() return p` but it returns this
[image]

and in python I get this that i don't know how to parse:

```
<Path start=<Node id=93 labels=frozenset({'a'}) properties={'name': 'A'}> end=<Node id=94 labels=frozenset({'b'}) properties={'name': 'B'}> size=1>
<Path start=<Node id=93 labels=frozenset({'a'}) properties={'name': 'A'}> end=<Node id=95 labels=frozenset({'c'}) properties={'name': 'C'}> size=2>
<Path start=<Node id=93 labels=frozenset({'a'}) properties={'name': 'A'}> end=<Node id=96 labels=frozenset({'d'}) properties={'name': 'D'}> size=1>
```

Edit: I discovered function nodes() so I tried with `match p=(:a)-[:r*..]->() return nodes(p)` that returns kinda what I need:

[image]

but it still duplicates the path `a,b,c` in `a,b` and `a,b,c`. How can I remove the first row?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question of duplicate path, one trick is to exclude paths whose end node is not a leaf, ie there are relationships starting from it. E.g.:

```
MATCH p=(parent {name: "a"})-[:r*1..10]->(child)
WHERE NOT (child)-[:r]->()
RETURN p
```

For your second question about the return format, you can use a combination of `UNWIND` and `collect` like this:

```
MATCH p=(parent {name: "a"})-[:r*1..10]->(child)
WHERE NOT (child)-[:r]->()
UNWIND nodes(p) as node
WITH p, collect(node.name) as names
RETURN names
```

The result is:

```
╒═════════════╕
│"names"      │
╞═════════════╡
│["a","b","c"]│
├─────────────┤
│["a","d"]    │
└─────────────┘
```

Comment: great thank you! Do you know what do I need to change if I don't want the starting node to be returned each time?

Comment: You can exclude it by adding `WITH p, node WHERE node.name <> 'a'` after the `UNWIND` clause

Comment: thank you, but what if I don't know attributes values? What if I just know the label? Is there a way to do the same as `node.name <> 'a'` but with the label?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32817282/4709400